# Argument in bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script called countscript.sh

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 echo "Running" $0
  3 tr -cs A-Za-z '\n' | tr A-Z a-z | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed $1 q
```

But I don't understand how to pass the argument correctly: ( "3" should be the argument $1 of sed).

```
$ echo " one two two three three three" | ./countscript.sh 3
Running ./countscript.sh
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: missing command
```

This works fine:

```
    $ echo "one two three four one one four" | tr -cs A-Za-z '\n' | tr A-Z a-z | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed 3q
  3 one
  2 four
  1 two
```

Thanks.

PS: Anybody else noticed the

bug in this script on page 10, [https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/don-knuth/pearls-2.pdf](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/cs257/archive/don-knuth/pearls-2.pdf) ?

Comment: The whitespace is a bit off; the pipeline in the linked paper should probably be read as `sed ${1}q`, not `sed ${1} q`.

Comment: The paper was also written in a different time; it should be quoted as `sed "${1}q"`, at least.

Comment: By way of explanation, the `sed` script `3q` indicates that `sed` should exit after reading the 3rd line. By default, `sed` outputs each line that it reads.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the extra white space was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the quoted paper, I think you are misreading

```
sed ${1}q
```

as

```
sed ${1} q
```

and `sed` does not consider `3` by itself a valid command. The separate argument `q` is treated as an input file name. If the value of `$1` *did* result in a single valid `sed` script, you would have likely gotten an error for the missing input file `q`.

Proper shell programming would dictate this be written as

```
sed "${1}q"
```

or

```
sed "${1} q"
```

instead; with the space as *part* of the script, `sed` correctly outputs the first `$1` lines of input and exits.

---

It's somewhat curious that the authors used `sed` instead of `head - "$1"` to output the first few lines, as one of them (McIlroy) essentially invented the idea of the Unix pipeline as a series of special-purpose, narrowly focused tools. Not having read the full paper, I don't know what Knuth and McIlroy's contributions to the paper were; perhaps Bentley just likes `sed`. :)

Answer (score 1):

When running the following command:

```sh
$ echo " one two two three three three" | ./countscript.sh 3
```

the special variable `$1` will be replaced by `3`, your first argument. Hence, the script runs:

```sh
tr -cs A-Za-z '\n' | tr A-Z a-z | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed 3 q
```

Notice the space between the `3` and the `q`. `sed` does not know what to do, because you give it no command (`3` is not a command).

Remove the space, and you should be fine.

```sh
tr -cs A-Za-z '\n' | tr A-Z a-z | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed "${1}q"
```